# Conditional re-rendering inside rich popup panel

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I'm using the rich faces popup panel which contains the search criteria and the search results. I need to render the search results on click of he search button. I'm using `<a4j:commandButton>` for search button, on click of the button the results are not rendering.

`<a4j:commandButton id="popupSearchButton" action="#{riskAreaSearchBean.search}"
    styleClass="saveAsDraft" immediate="true" execute="areaPopupSearch"
    value="#{riskLabel['customs.common.search']}" render="addAreaPopupPanel" />`

"addAreaPopupPanel" is my popup panel id

Comment: Try without `immediate="true" execute="areaPopupSearch"`. If it works add one of them and check result.

Answer (score 0):

If your addAreaPopupPanel is having rendered attribute set to false before onclick of your search button there is no chance of finding it in the DOM tree. Enclose it in a `h:panelGroup` or `h:paneGrid` which will always present in DOM and render that panelGroup or panelGrid.

*remove `immediate=true` as it will skip update modal values phase.

Hope this helps.